# How to deserialize dates with offset ("2019-01-29+01:00") to `java.time` related classes?

Tags: kotlin, java-8, jackson, jsr310, java-time

I've refactored some legacy code within Spring Boot (2.1.2) system and migrated from `java.util.Date` to `java.time` based classes (jsr310). The system expects the dates in a ISO8601 formated string, whereas some are complete timestamps with time information (e.g. `"2019-01-29T15:29:34+01:00"`) while others are only dates with offset (e.g. `"2019-01-29+01:00"`). Here is the DTO (as Kotlin data class):

```
data class Dto(
        // ...
        @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")
        @JsonProperty("processingTimestamp")
        val processingTimestamp: OffsetDateTime,

        // ...
        @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING,  pattern = "yyyy-MM-ddXXX")
        @JsonProperty("orderDate")
        val orderDate: OffsetDateTime,
        // ...
)
```

While Jackson perfectly deserializes `processingTimestamp`, it fails with `orderDate`:

```
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {OffsetSeconds=32400},ISO resolved to 2018-10-23 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.OffsetDateTime.from(OffsetDateTime.java:370) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.InstantDeserializer.deserialize(InstantDeserializer.java:207) ~[jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
```

This makes sense to me, since `OffsetDateTime` cannot find any time information necessary to construct the instant. If I change to `val orderDate: LocalDate` Jackson can successfully deserialize, but then the offset information is gone (which I need to convert to `Instant` later).

## Question

My current workaround is to use `OffsetDateTime`, in combination with a custom deserializer (see below). **But I'm wondering, if there is a better solution for this?**

Also, I'd wish for a more appropriate data type like *OffsetDate*, but I cannot find it in [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).

#### PS

I was asking myself if "2019-01-29+01:00" is a valid for ISO8601. However, since I found that [`java.time.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_DATE) is can correctly parse it and I cannot change the format how the clients send data, I put aside this question.

#### Workaround

```
data class Dto(
        // ...
        @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING,  pattern = "yyyy-MM-ddXXX")
        @JsonProperty("catchDate")
        @JsonDeserialize(using = OffsetDateDeserializer::class)
        val orderDate: OffsetDateTime,
        // ...
)

class OffsetDateDeserializer(
        private val formatter: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE
) : JSR310DateTimeDeserializerBase<OffsetDateTime>(OffsetDateTime::class.java, formatter) {


    override fun deserialize(parser: JsonParser, context: DeserializationContext): OffsetDateTime? {
        if (parser.hasToken(JsonToken.VALUE_STRING)) {
            val string = parser.text.trim()
            if (string.isEmpty()) {
                return null
            }

            val parsed: TemporalAccessor = formatter.parse(string)
            val offset = if(parsed.isSupported(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS)) ZoneOffset.from(parsed) else ZoneOffset.UTC
            val localDate = LocalDate.from(parsed)
            return OffsetDateTime.of(localDate.atStartOfDay(), offset)
        }
        throw context.wrongTokenException(parser, _valueClass, parser.currentToken, "date with offset must be contained in string")
    }

    override fun withDateFormat(otherFormatter: DateTimeFormatter?): JsonDeserializer<OffsetDateTime> = OffsetDateDeserializer(formatter)
}
```

Comment: An `OffsetDate` class was considered for JSR-310, but it was pushed back as having minimal use cases. Using `OffsetDateTime` is your best option in the JDK. You can parse the format using `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and `parseDefaulting`.

Comment: @JodaStephen thank you so much for the clarification! I take your suggestion and create an answer for my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JodaStephen explained in the comments, *OffsetDate* was not included in `java.time` to have a minimal set of classes. So, `OffsetDateTime` is the best option.

He also suggested to use `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and `parseDefaulting` to create a `DateTimeFormatter` instance, to directly create `OffsetDateTime` from the formatters parsing result (`TemporalAccessor`). AFAIK, I still need to create a custom deserializer to use the formatter. Here is code, which solved my problem:

```
class OffsetDateDeserializer: JsonDeserializer<OffsetDateTime>() {

    private val formatter = DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 0)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, 0)
            .toFormatter()


    override fun deserialize(parser: JsonParser, context: DeserializationContext): OffsetDateTime? {
        if (parser.hasToken(JsonToken.VALUE_STRING)) {
            val string = parser.text.trim()
            if (string.isEmpty()) {
                return null
            }
            try {
                return OffsetDateTime.from(formatter.parse(string))
            } catch (e: DateTimeException){
                throw context.wrongTokenException(parser, OffsetDateTime::class.java, parser.currentToken, "error while parsing date: ${e.message}")
            }
        }
        throw context.wrongTokenException(parser, OffsetDateTime::class.java, parser.currentToken, "date with offset must be contained in string")
    }
}
```